# Can one move the OCRed text from one PDF to another PDF file?

Tags: pdf

Given a PDF file with OCRed text, is it possible to move the OCRed text to another PDF file?

Comment: What applications did you have in mind here?

Comment: pdftk, gs, python, ...?

Comment: Can you be more clear? Do you want to strip all that is not text from the PDF? I ask because if not, when you have the text you can always use a word processor and find a way to print a PDF file. (or you can use LaTeX...)

Comment: @Hastur: In an extreme example where there are two pdf files that are identical except that one has OCRed text and the other doesn't, I want to make the second the same as the first.